# Format on save with Prettier in Promises

Tags: javascript, formatting, prettier

Is there a way to fix the format with promises in VS Code?
when I format with prettier or any other options, the code look like this /

```
const GET_USERS = () => {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then((resolve) => {
    resolve.json().then((json) => {
      console.log(json);
    });
  });
};

and I really want that the code look like this \/, without stop using prettier

const GET_USERS = () => {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then((resolve) => {resolve.json()
    .then((json) => {console.log(json);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Taking a look to prettier docs, seems that there's no configurable option to do that https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html

Comment: VSCode is a more accurate depiction of what you are doing, since you are nesting the `.then` - if you want your `.then` to look like a so-called chain, write them as one

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
const GET_USERS = () => {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
    .then((resolve) => resolve.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json);
    });
   // catch errors here
};
```

Check how I'm chaining promises, one after another. Don't forget to use a catch for errors. Also, maybe you are trying to return something from that function?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
// prettier-ignore
const GET_USERS = () => {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then((resolve) => {resolve.json()
    .then((json) => {console.log(json);
    });
  });
};
```